# Is it possible to specify multiple types for a function parameter?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

It is possible in C++ define a function argument to be of more than one type?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
   void  PrintA() { cout << "A" << endl;}
};

class B {
public:
   void  PrintB() { cout << "B" << endl;}
};

class C: public A, public B {
public:
   C(){;}
};

class D: public A, public B {
public:
   D(){;}
};

///
void __printall__(A*a, B*b){
   a->PrintA();
   b->PrintB();
}
#define printall(a) __printall__(a,a)
///

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   C c;
   D d;
   printall(&c);
   printall(&d);
}
```

I want to change the code between the comments with something not using macros. I would not force the pointers cast because I want to preserve the type safety. I would not even introduce another class between C/D and A/B because actually my class hierarchy is a bit more complex of that shown in the code, and it is not desirable to rebase all the class that derive from A or B

Comment: What about templates? Variadic templates etc? Have a look here : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2087.pdf

Comment: I would recommend a different design to remove this issue in the first place. Make a `Print` method in `C` and `D` which calls it's base class's print functions.

Answer (score 5):

Like [@Torsten advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11539772/20984), a possible solution is to use a function template so that you can pass any type of arguments. However, a simple template will work with any type that provides the appropriate members (in this case `printA` and `printB`), so the following function template

```
template <typename T>
void printAll(T const & t)
{
    t.printA();
    t.printB();
}
```

will work with the following type

```
struct Foo
{
    void printA() const { std::cout << "FooA\n"; }
    void printB() const { std::cout << "FooB\n"; }
}

printAll(Foo());
```

even though `Foo` does not derive from `A` or `B`. This might be desirable, but if you really want to enforce the fact that the argument must be a `A` and a `B`, you can use a static assertion in your function to check that:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void printAll(T const & t)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value && std::is_base_of<B, T>::value,
                  "T must be derived from A and B");

    t.printA();
    t.printB();
}
```

An alternate solution would be to use `std::enable_if` to define the function template only when the template parameter is indeed a derived class of `A` and `B`:

```
template<
    typename T ,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_base_of<A, T>::value &&
        std::is_base_of<B, T>::value
    >::type
>
void printAll(T const & t)
{
    t.printA();
    t.printB();
}
```

---

*N.B*: `static_assert`, `enable_if` and `is_base_of` are C++11 features. If you are working with C++03, you can find the equivalent in various Boost libraries.

Comment: I think the last code you wrote is exactly what I was searching for! I will test it soon. Tank you!

Comment: @user1534420 Did it work? If so please mark the answer correct, or explain why this doesn't fit your needs in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

a template version will just pick the type, that is passed to the function:

```
template < class T >
void printall( T* t )
{
   t->printA();
   t->printB();
}
```

Comment: It is not what I want. I want to call printA and printB BOTH !

Comment: You don't even need `printA` and `printB`, just define the template and call `t->PrintA()` and `t->PrintB()` directly in `printall`

Comment: No. The code is wrong because when calling printall(c) it can't figure out witch function to call. Also, if for example it call the printall<A>, it cannot access to printB method. You can try to compile to convince yourself.

Comment: @user1534420 the problem is, that your requirements are very unclear.

Comment: @user1534420 "_it can't figure out witch function to call_" what do you mean? it compiles fine.

Comment: @user1534420: when you call `printall(&c)`, the compiler instantiate the function template with `C`, generating a function akin to the following: `void printall(C * c) { c->printA(); c->printB(); }`. Since `C` provides both `printA` and `printB` member functions, the code compiles perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Torsten is right. Instead, if are looking something like "late binding" at run-time you could use a function pointer. You can find a clear example [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/intro.html#why).